# Xamarin Using DataContractJsonSerializer for Android Blank App

Tags: xamarin, serialization, xamarin.android, datacontractserializer, datacontractjsonserializer

I am trying to use DataContractJsonSerializer but I can't seem to get a reference/namespace for it. 
I created my app on a .NET Framework 4.5.

When I click add reference I only get the version 2.0.5.0 for System.ServiceModel

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get DataContractJsonSerializer working with Android you would need to create a PCL project and then it would be available under namespace System.Runtime.Serialization.Json. This would require a Xamarin business license or higher to work.

Better option would be to use Json.NET (much faster than DataContractJsonSerializer if you use it more than once) or ServiceStack.Text ([much faster than Json.NET](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9886/quick-json-serializer-performance-test-json-net-vs-servicestack/p1)). XLabs offers an abstraction on mobile compatible serializers ([Nuget, search for XLabs.Serialization](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=xlabs.serialization)) and has plugins for Json.NET, ServiceStack.Text (v3), ProtoBuf & of course DataContractSerializer (.NET XML serializer). DataContractJsonSerializer is omitted from the package since it requires business license and really doesn't offer much over Json.NET or ServiceStack.

Answer (score -1):

DataContractJsonSerializer will not work with Xamarin.
I use Newtonsoft.Json nuget package to work with json serialization and till now haven't found any problem with it. 
It's very simple:

string str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);